# sqlite database schema version incrementing on disconnect/connect from sqlitestudio

Tags: sqlite, sqlitestudio

I use the sqlite database schema version.

```
PRAGMA schema_version;
```

It helps me control upgrades and prevents user from modifying the schema and then reporting a flood of irreproducible bugs.

However, I find the version increments far more often that I expect.

*" It is incremented by SQLite whenever the database schema is modified (by creating or dropping a table or index). "* http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version

In particular when I simply connect and disconnect from sqlitestudio, even though I do not change the schema in any way.

Is there any way of preventing this happening ( or at least understanding what is going on ) ?

Comment: What does uploading the database to the cloud and then downloading it again mean, specifically? For application database versioning, prefer `pragma user_version`.

Comment: pragam user_version does not work for me, since it is NOT incremented when the user created or drops a table AFAIK.  I am talking about such  as uploading and downloading from dropbox.